# Xamarin: Portable Library have no System.Drawing?

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, system.drawing

I am new in Xamarin. I am trying to build a portable library for all platform. I realized I can't import System.Drawing. Is there a way to add that library in.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat

Comment: The `System.Drawing`  namespace is not cross-platform. For Xamarin cross-platform 2D drawing, have a look at [SkiaSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/).